# How to get smooth transitions in pure JavaScript and CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I have `div` elements with a black background-color that get and loose the class `animated` that has an css definition for an animated colored background. The animation is working smooth. But the change from the black to the animated state and back are not. I tried some transition rules but I can not figure out how to get a smooth change.

Here is my minimal example:

```js
let randomNumber;
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".dark");
let randomNumbers = [];
let milliseconds = 2000;
setInterval(function() {
  randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * boxes.length);
  randomNumbers.push(randomNumber);
  boxes[randomNumber].className = boxes[randomNumber].className.replace(/(?:^|\s)dark(?!\S)/g, " animated");
  setTimeout(function() {
    boxes[randomNumbers[0]].className = boxes[randomNumbers[0]].className.replace(/(?:^|\s)animated(?!\S)/g, " dark");
    randomNumbers.shift();
  }, boxes.length * milliseconds);
}, milliseconds);
```

```css
@keyframes animated_background_color {
  0% {
    background-color: #e66000;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: #ff9500;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #ffcb00;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: #ff9500;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #e66000;
  }
}

.box {
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  width: 20px;
}

.dark {
  background-color: black;
}

.animated {
  animation-name: animated_background_color;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  background-color: #e66000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Animation</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box dark"></div>
  <div class="box dark"></div>
  <div class="box dark"></div>
  <div class="box dark"></div>
  <div class="box dark"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Instead of `linear` (for your `animation-timing-function`) you could use one of the "easing" animation timing functions as explained here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-timing-function.asp

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68137414/how-to-get-smooth-transitions-in-pure-javascript-and-css#comment120431389_68138482) of [devdgehog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14438744/devdgehog), I decided to add more keyframes. Now I switch from the dark state to the animated state and back again with the first and last keyframe setting the dark background and the other keyframes switching from orange to bright orange to yellow to bright orange to orange three times in a row.

```js
const DARK_SELECTOR = ".dark";
const DARK_CLASS = "dark";
const ANIMATED_CLASS = "animated";
const ANIMATION_CYCLE_TIME = 6000;

function animateRandomBox(animationTime) {
  const darkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll(DARK_SELECTOR);
  const numberOfDarkBoxes = darkBoxes.length;
  if (numberOfDarkBoxes === 0) {
    return;
  }
  const randomBoxNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfDarkBoxes);
  const randomBoxClass = darkBoxes[randomBoxNumber].classList;
  randomBoxClass.remove('dark');
  randomBoxClass.add('animated');
  setTimeout(() => {
    randomBoxClass.add('dark');
    randomBoxClass.remove('animated');
  }, animationTime);
}

setInterval(() => animateRandomBox(ANIMATION_CYCLE_TIME), ANIMATION_CYCLE_TIME);
```

```css
@keyframes animated_background_color {
  0% {
    background-color: #000;
  }
  12% {
    background-color: #ff9500;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: #ffcb00;
  }
  37% {
    background-color: #ff9500;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #ffcb00;
  }
  62% {
    background-color: #ff9500;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: #ffcb00;
  }
  87% {
    background-color: #ff9500;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #000;
  }
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: min-content;
  row-gap: 0.25rem;
}

.box {
  height: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.dark {
  background-color: black;
}

.animated {
  animation-name: animated_background_color;
  animation-duration: 6s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Animation</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box dark"></div>
  <div class="box dark"></div>
  <div class="box dark"></div>
  <div class="box dark"></div>
  <div class="box dark"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your starting and ending colors are not black, that's one reason why you see a shift. replace your 0% and 100% values by `background-color: black;`.

Once this problem is fixed, you will have a problem with your `milliseconds` variable because it's not a divider of your animation time (here 5*2000ms, which means the .animated class remove the class at 10s when your animation cycle is 3s)

---

Bonus: I have no idea why I cleaned and modified your code but I did it. (I'm tired and it was ugly)

```js
const DARK_SELECTOR = ".dark";
const DARK_CLASS = "dark";
const ANIMATED_CLASS = "animated";
const ANIMATION_CYCLE_TIME = 2000;
const TOTAL_ANIMATION_TIME = 3 * ANIMATION_CYCLE_TIME;
const TIME_BETWEEN_ANIMATIONS = 1.5 * ANIMATION_CYCLE_TIME;

function animateRandomBox(animationTime) {
  const darkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll(DARK_SELECTOR);
  const numberOfDarkBoxes = darkBoxes.length;
  if (numberOfDarkBoxes === 0) {
    return;
  }
  const randomBoxNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfDarkBoxes);
  const randomBoxClass = darkBoxes[randomBoxNumber].classList;
  randomBoxClass.remove('dark');
  randomBoxClass.add('animated');
  setTimeout(() => {
    randomBoxClass.add('dark');
    randomBoxClass.remove('animated');
  }, animationTime);
}

setInterval(() => animateRandomBox(TOTAL_ANIMATION_TIME), TIME_BETWEEN_ANIMATIONS);
```

```css
@keyframes animated_background_color {
  0% {
    background-color: #000;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: #ff9500;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #ffcb00;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: #ff9500;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #000;
  }
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: min-content;
  row-gap: 0.25rem;
}

.box {
  height: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.dark {
  background-color: black;
}

.animated {
  animation-name: animated_background_color;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Animation</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box dark"></div>
  <div class="box dark"></div>
  <div class="box dark"></div>
  <div class="box dark"></div>
  <div class="box dark"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But now the animation just runs once before the elements get black again and I want it to switch multiple times between the first and last color of the animation before the element gets black again.

Comment: It was not specified.
1) You can use another class (example .orange) with a transition: .dark-> .orange -> .animated -> .orange -> .dark with 0% and 100% set to orange colors
2) You can use only transitions: .dark -> .orange -> .yellow -> .orange -> .yellow -> ... -> .orange -> .dark
3) You can insert more keyframes in your animation to do dark color -> orange color -> yellow color -> orange -> yellow -> ... -> orange color -> dark color. Obviously you need to change animation time in css and scripts